# Need help in joining 4 tables

Tags: sql, join

I have following 4 tables.

T1

```
    +------+-------+-------------+------+
    | type | pcode | ccode       | amnt |
    +------+-------+-------------+------+
    | s    |     1 |        1801 | 1000 |
    | s    |     1 |        1801 | 2000 |
    | s    |     1 |        1801 | 3000 |
    | s    |     2 |        1802 | 1500 |
    | s    |     3 |        1802 | 2500 |
    +------+-------+-------------+------+
```

T2

```
+-------+-------+
| btype | Ccode |
+-------+-------+
|     0 |  1701 | 
|     0 |  1801 |
|     0 |  1801 |  
|     1 |  1801 |
|     0 |  1802 | 
|     1 |  1802 |  
+-------+-------+
```

T3

```
+-------+------+-------+
| pcode | name | scode |  
+-------+------+-------+
|     1 | pep  |  1001 |  
|     2 | coke |  1002 |  
+-------+------+-------+
```

T4

```
+------+------+
| code | name |
+------+------+
| 1001 | pep  |
| 1002 | coke |
+------+------+
```

The result set I need should satisfy the following condition.

I need t4.code, t4.name, sum(amount) as s1 if bill type =0, sum(t1.amount)as s2 if billtype =1

i.e the result set should be

```
+------+------+------+------+
| Code | name |  s1  |  s2  |
+------+------+------+------+
| 1001 | pep  | 3000 | 3000 |
| 1002 | coke | 1500 | 2500 |
+------+------+------+------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use inner join and case for filter then values to sum

```
select t4.code, t4.name
  , sum(CASE WHEN t2.btype=0 then T1.amnt else 0 end) s1
  , sum(CASE WHEN t2.btype=1 then T1.amnt else 0 end) s2

from T4
INNER JOIN T3 on T3.scode = T4.code
INNER JOIN T1 on T3.pcode = T1.pcode
INNER JOIN T2 on T1.ccode = t2.ccode
```

Comment: Thank you but i get same values in s1 and s2. Both are showing the sum of s1 and s2 i.e 6000, 4000 respectively.

Comment: looking to your data .. you have  both ptype for 1801 and 1082 ... this is the reason ..  you should have only a ptype for each code  ..